# In given array I have only 2 zeroes but the i is showing 4. Please explain it for me

Tags: javascript

Given array to be executed here is `[0, 1, 0, 3, 12]`.

```
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
    for (let i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if (nums[i] === 0){
            nums.push(0);
            console.log(nums)
            console.log(i)
            nums.splice(i, 1)
        }
    }
};

moveZeroes([0, 1, 0, 3, 12]);
```

Result is

```
[0, 1, 0, 3, 12, 0]
›0
›[1, 0, 3, 12, 0, 0]
›1
›[1, 3, 12, 0, 0, 0]
›3
›[1, 3, 12, 0, 0, 0]
›4
›[1, 3, 12, 0, 0]
```

I am not understanding how is the code working.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the **expected behavior should be**. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. **Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question**."_

Comment: Don't change the (length of the) collection you're iterating over unless you know exactly what consequences these changes have.

Comment: by "moving" the zero it will be found again on different index

Comment: @johnSmith This will also skip the number after the zero

Comment: Whenever zero is met in the loop, the code adds a new member (having value zero) at the end of the array, and deletes the member where zero was found.

Comment: The code iterates over `nums` array while at the same time altering the same `nums` array which in turn gives unintended consequences. Please take a copy of `nums` array (say, `const nums2 = [...nums];`) and iterate over the copy (ie, `nums2`) while changing (ie, `splice`) on `nums` array.

Comment: The code works as it is. The extra zeros you see in the console are appended to the array during the process, if you'd moved the loggings at the of the `if` block, you wouldn't see extra zeros at all.

Comment: @Abhishek Kumar 107, The code is working like you are trying to put all zeroes at the end by adding at the back and deleting it from the position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const moveZeroes = function(nums) {
  // Iterate through each element of the array and save the index on `i`
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    // If the current element of the iteration has value 0, execute...
    if (nums[i] === 0) {
      // Push a `0` at the end of the array
      nums.push(0);
      // Print current index of the loop
      console.log(i)
      // Print current state of the array. At this point the array would
      // have length = 6 since we have added a `0` at the end of the array
      console.log(nums)
      // In this case the splice function is used to remove a element
      // of the array at index `i`. The argument `1` means to remove 1 element 
      // from index `i`
      nums.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
};

const array = [0, 1, 0, 3, 12];

// Take into account that I'm passing the array by reference
// (not by value). It means that the function would modify the `array` elements
moveZeroes(array);
console.log("Result", array);
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to move all the zeros to the end of the array. The ***i*** indicates the current number of the index in the loop.
In each loop, the ***i*** will increase by 1, and since you moved all the zeros to the end of the array, the ***if*** condition will run and show you the number 4 at the end of the ***for-loop***.
This question shows that you need to know the fundamentals of the array and for-loop. these links below will help you to grasp how for-loops and arrays work

- [Arrys](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)
- [for-loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

**Let's look at you code**

```js
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] === 0) {
      // push new 0 to the end of given array
      nums.push(0);
      // print the changed array
      console.log(nums)
      //print the current iteration number
      console.log(i)
      // in this case the splice method will remove the 
      // element in index `i`. the argument `1` indicates
      // to remove 1 element after the index `1`
      nums.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
};

moveZeroes([0, 1, 0, 3, 12]);
```

**The code below will do the same thing without mutating the original array**

```js
function moveZeroes(nums) {
  const newArray = []

  // the loop will iterate based on the length of the array plus
  // the number of zeros
  for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < nums.length + j; i++) {

    // push the non-zero numbers to the new array
    if (i < nums.length && nums[i]) newArray.push(nums[i])

    // count the zeros
    else if (i < nums.length) j++;

    // push zeros to the end of the array when the iteration
    // is beyond the length of the array
    else newArray.push(0);
  }
  return newArray
};

console.log(moveZeroes([0, 1, 0, 3, 12]))
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the question you have only two zeros but i is showing 4 because, your iterating through array by loop , and i indicates index here with which we identify the position of array elements.array index start from 0 and  array has total 5 elements hence at the last iteration i will be 4

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you

```
const moveZeroes = function(nums) {
let newArr= [];
let zeros = [];
for(let i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
    if (nums[i]=== 0) {
        zeros.push(0)
    }
    else{
        newArr.push(nums[i])
    }
}

return newArr.concat(zeros)};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).